# Amazon's AWS elasticache - c# example

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, memcached, amazon-elasticache

Does anyone have example code that use C# to connect to a AWS elasticache (memcached) cluster?

I've found [this](https://jacace.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/using-the-amazon-elasticache-in-c/) example but it seems a bit old(the library is from 2010). [This github library](https://github.com/awslabs/elasticache-cluster-config-net) may work. There aren't many examples out there.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Got it working with this [pluralsight](http://Optimizing%20and%20Managing%20Distributed%20Systems%20on%20AWS) video by Richard Seroter.

**Steps:**

Add the following nuget package: EnyimMemCached

Then add this **inside** the configSections node in your web config:

```
<sectionGroup name="enyim.com">
      <section name="memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Configuration.MemcachedClientSection, Enyim.Caching"/>
    </sectionGroup>
```

Then Add this just **below** the system.web node( so it's a sibling node to system.web).  Be sure to replace the url and port with your elasticache endpoint :

```
<enyim.com>
    <memcached>
      <servers>
        <add address="...your elasticache url here...." port="your port here..."></add>
      </servers>
    </memcached>
  </enyim.com>
```

Then in my view action i called set a cache value and read it out. It only works when it's been published and is running on AWS.(wasn't working locally):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var client = new MemcachedClient();

            string myCacheKey = "MyCacheKey";
            client.Store(Enyim.Caching.Memcached.StoreMode.Set, myCacheKey, "If you see this it worked.");  // set the cache.
            string myCachedString = client.Get<string>(myCacheKey);

            ViewBag.MyCache = myCachedString ?? "**** SORRY,  DIDN'T WORK..***..";
            return View();

        }
```

Hop this helps someone.